# Not able to upload a file in selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I have recorded a selenium test case of choosing a file with browse button. The code is:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("file")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("file")).sendKeys("C://abc.sql");
```

I have confirmed that the file exists.
The code of the web page is as follows:

```
<input title="Search" name="file" id="file" value="Search" type="file">
```

Please help.

Comment: What are the symptoms? Any errors?

Answer (score 1):

I didnt test it as i dont have idea where you are trying to upload the file..But i think problem will be in absolute path of the file.Try to use this.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("file")).sendKeys("C:\\abc.sql");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you clicked the Button after entering the text "C://abc.sql" in the input text field ?

Like after giving the path of file we must click the upload button to submit it

```
driver.findElement(By.id("file")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("file")).sendKeys("C:\\abc.sql");
driver.findElement(By.id("uploadbutton")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try '**element(browseTextbox).type("pathToTheFile");**' If the problem lies with clicking of browse button, then probably use better xpath based on text or use **Fluent Wait**.

Answer (score -1):

If you have to browse and and add files, then better try AutoIT. because selenium is entirely browser based and it will not control windows based controls.

Tutorials are available here on AutoIT :- https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/Tutorials

Comment: Actually the Brouse button does not get clicked.After waiting for some time,it gives error:-

Comment: Please paste the your code for clicking Browse button. If possible, show screenshot of that page